# passing another object into current rest service does not throw an exception

Tags: java, rest, spring-mvc, error-handling

this my is rest request that is compatible for another service :

```
{
  "fromDate": 1562773101000,
  "toDate": 1563118701000,
  "turnOverType": 4,
  "fromAmount": 1,
  "toAmount": 10000000,
  "voucherDescription": null,
  "articleDescription": null,
  "referenceNumbers": [],
  "offset": 3,
  "pageSize": 20,
  "iban": "BLAHBLAHBLAHBLAH"
}
```

and this is corresponding model that not match request :

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlRootElement(name = "TransferRequestInquiryFilter")
public class TransferRequestInquiryFilter implements Serializable {
    @XmlElement(name = "sourceIbans")
    private List<String> sourceIbans;
    @XmlElement(name = "transferType")
    private TransferType transferType;
    @XmlElement(name = "fromTransferDate")
    private Timestamp fromTransferDate;
    @XmlElement(name = "toTransferDate")
    private Timestamp toTransferDate;
    @XmlElement(name = "fromRegistrationDate")
    private Timestamp fromRegistrationDate;
    @XmlElement(name = "toRegistrationDate")
    private Timestamp toRegistrationDate;
    @XmlElement(name = "trackingNumbers")
    private List<String> trackingNumbers;
    @XmlElement(name = "referenceNumbers")
    private List<String> referenceNumbers;
    @XmlElement(name = "transactionIds")
    private List<String> transactionIds;
    @XmlElement(name = "status")
    private TransactionStatus status;
    @XmlElement(name = "fromAmount")
    private Long fromAmount;
    @XmlElement(name = "toAmount")
    private Long toAmount;
    @XmlElement(name = "destinationIbans")
    private List<String> destinationIbans;
```

and this is my controller ..

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/inquiry", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public @ResponseBody
ResponseEntity<List<ExtendedTransferRequest>> transferInquiry(@RequestBody @Valid TransferRequestInquiryFilter transferRequestInquiryFilter
        , BindingResult bindingResult) {

    // when validation not works return bad request
    List<ErrorObject> errorObjects = requestInquiryValidator.validate(transferRequestInquiryFilter);
    if (errorObjects.size() > 0) {
        // just throw bad request and not detail of them
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.BAD_REQUEST);
    }

    List<ExtendedTransferRequest> extendedTransferRequestList = new ArrayList<>();
    ExtendedTransferRequest extendedTransferRequest = new ExtendedTransferRequest();
    List<SettlementTransaction> settlementTransactionList = settlementSearch.findSettlement(transferRequestInquiryFilter);
    extendedTransferRequestList = TransferInquiryResponseMapper.INSTANCE.SettlementTransactionInquiryResponse(setlementTransactionList);
    return new ResponseEntity<>(extendedTransferRequestList, HttpStatus.OK);

}
```

just fromAmount and toAmount fills. but i want to get an exception for this situation and throw a bad request for client. how can i do that? If I get name conflict or type conflict between rest request and model , I need to handle it and riase a bad request for client. i am using spring mvc 5 and jackson-core and jackson-databind 2.9.4

Comment: It is not at all clear exactly what your question is.

Comment: argument of service is different from rest request , in such situation HttpMessageNotReadableException is expected. but no exception occures.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using validation-api, annotate proper validation for fields and `@validated` before controller method and using `@valid` before `RequestBody` object would throw proper validation exception.